# How can I access an array of objects within a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

How can I access objects that sit within an array, which is itself inside a JSON object?

**JSON Structure:**

```
{
    "name":"animals",
    "type":"farmyard",
    "version": "1.0",

    "items": [{
        {
            "name": "pig",
            "description": "pink, round"
        },

        {
            "name": "chicken",
            "description": "small, yellow"
        }
    }]

}
```

**And here is the JS so far...**

```
    $.getJSON( "https://_LINK_TO_JSON.json", function( data ) {

      var farm = [];
      var animals = [];

      $.each( data, function( key, val ) {

        farm.push(key, val);

        var animals = farm[3];
        console.dir(animals);

      });

      console.dir(animals);

    });
```

I've tried to use `farm.items` to target the array, but that didn't work so I've used the index number instead.

(Naturally, using `farm.items[1].name` to target the first name didn't work either.)

Is the reason I can't just use dot notation something to do with the fact that JSON `keys` and `values`are within quote marks? (I can't actually edit the JSON feed as it's external).

How can I simply target the nested array and grab items I want and their properties?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. The outer level of `{ }` in the "items" array is probably a typo. If so, then iterating through `data.items` would give you access to the elements of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use $eaach function of jquery as

```
$.getJSON (urltoJSON, function(data){
$.each(data.response.venue.items, function (index, value) {
    console.log(this.name);
    console.log(this.description);
 });
});
```

also you can save the json in a javascript variable and iterate over it as

```
data= 'get ur  json'
for ( i in data.items ) {
   console.log ( i.name + "" )
   console.log ( i.description + "" );    
    }
```

Comment: This actually solved it. I was able to access the nested array and console log some of the properties :)

Comment: Weirdly I have everything looping through everything and working in `console.logs`, however when I do this: `$('.container').html('<li> <a href="' + this.link + '" target="_blank">' + '<img src="' + this.thumbnail + '"/>' + this.name + '</a> </li>');` it just spits out the last object and nothing else?

Comment: OK, realised that the loops working okay. It's just only working with the first item, then giving me a `/null` value, followed by 404s for 2 subsequent objects? Is this something to do with the way I'm making the request?

Comment: well everything is treated as javascriptObjects first. if you want text then use JSON.stringify(). also if you want to loop over some of items, change for loop to traditional one

Comment: also try to print the json response and verify if that is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You have error in your JSON structure. Your JSON need to be:

```
var data = {
    'name':'animals',
    'type':'farmyard',
    'version': '1.0',

    'items': [
        {
            'name': 'pig',
            'description': 'pink, round'
        },

        {
            'name': 'chicken',
            'description': 'small, yellow'
        }
    ]

};

console.log(data.items);
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/6uhp6y34/

Comment: Ah right, thanks. OK so the error with the external JSON is holding me back! :(